# Accessing keys in appSettings in App.config across multiple projects in solution

Tags: c#, app-config, appsettings

I've got a C# solution of about 7 different projects, each with their own class to access our database.  Right now I'm storing the database server, username, and password in the AppSettings of the app.config file for the startup project.

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="dbServer" value="localhost"/>
    <add key ="dbUser" value ="admin"/>
    <add key ="dbPassword" value ="pw"/>
  </appSettings>
 ...
</configuration>
```

In the same startup project, I have created a class to query for these values:

```
public static class DBConfiguration
{
    public static String getDBServer
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbServer"]; }
    }

    public static String getDBUser
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbUser"]; }
    }

    public static String getDBPassword
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbPassword"]; }
    }
}
```

Right now when I am in my Unit Test project, I am trying to call `DBConfiguration.getDBServer`, `DBConfiguration.getDBUser`, etc. and it is returning null.  If I copy the same appSettings into the UT app.config, I get results.  I'm a little confused how that is working.  Since DBConfiguration is located in startup - shouldn't the calls to DBConfiguration refer to the app.config in startup as well?

Also, I have already added the reference to `System.Configuration`.

Comment: see edit. I would like to see more on what scencario you guys face to require a difference

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is by design. `ConfigurationManager` will pull settings from the current executing assembly. So if your unit test is the current executing assembly `ConfigurationManager` will get its settings from that app.config. This is useful for scenarios where you connect to different databases for testing purposes (which...you should be)

**EDIT**

ok so based on what you just mentioned about how you have things set up I feel compelled to ask why do you have it setup this way, and why do you have checks to see if you are in production or not. Sure there are valid reasons for it, but I think 99% of the time it can be avoided with a little forsight. However since your post was more about the app.config file I'll stick to that. When you have the same devs all needing to test some interaction with the database there are a few approaches one could take. One approach (and the one i'm most familiar with) is to use the repository pattern where you have a interface that returns or sets things according to a class. typical boiler plat code would be something similar to this:

```
public interface IRobotRepository()
{
    IEnumerable<Robot> GetAllRobots();
    Robot GetRobot(RobotParameters parameters);
    void DeleteRobots();
    void DeleteRobot(Robot robotToDelete);
}
```

granted a repository does not have to have both getters and setters, the point is that it is a way of stating your intent of what you want out of a repository (such as a database). It is simple and the point which is what I'm getting at though. With it you can easily mock it out and test functionality that depends specifically on that data. No specific configuration needed just all in memory things. Then for integration tests you can test that the repositories work as intended. Although you can have said repository on each dev's computer (such as using SqlLocalDb, or Sqlite's in memory database) those require a little more work with keeping it in sync with production. Just gotta balance the cost with that. Another option is to have a common QA/Dev/Sandbox database that is shared. There are tradeoff's with this approach too but normally isn't a big deal.

Keep in mind though that this is just one approach and there are tons of other approaches that people will scream to death is the best way. I just want to point out that there are multiple approaches to having multiple devs testing against a database. I'd be interested to see what your approach ends up being and showing why you went that path.

Comment: We actually have 2 databases, one as a sandbox and one for production.  I have code down the line to differentiate between them, but the default database connection we use is localhost so that developers can play around with it on their own machines as well.  Is there anyway to perpetuate any of these variables across the entire solution?  This issue that we are hitting is that there are multiple locations where these variables are being declared and I am trying to have a setup where DB: production, sandbox, local is declared once and used throughout the entire solution.